# How to install kubernetes on a docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

Is this possible?

I want to create an image to run a kubernetes worker inside a docker container.

I tryed using dind images but it didn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: Kubernetes is a multi-host distributed cluster environment.  Do you just need the `kubectl` client?  Or are you looking for a single-host Kubernetes setup like [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io) that happens to run inside a container?

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a way to create an image with kubernetes on it, to make it easier to setup my kubernetes workers

Answer (score 4):

There are several options, for example the official kind (kubernetes in docker) project: https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/

Depending on your use case, k3s might be a good fit as well: https://k3s.io/ here is an example with docker-compose: https://www.trion.de/news/2019/08/28/kubernetes-in-docker-mit-k3s.html

Comment: I'd agree with the recommendation for kind, it works really well and can be configured for different types of operation.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a way to create a docker image with kubernetes configured on it, to make it easier to setup my kubernetes workers(clients) but I'm having problems when I try to do this with ubuntu images or dind images, do you know something that can help me?